# Open subset is compact iff it is finite

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a discrete space. Then, obviously, an open subset of $X$ is compact if and only if it is finite. Are there any other topological settings (coarse enough to be non-trivial) for infinite topological spaces to have this property?

Comment: One can make a trivial change, having two points that are in the same basic open set and otherwise the discrete topology.  How much is needed for it to be another setting?

Comment: @OpenBall:  isn't that the same as the discrete topology?

Comment: Yep, Ross is correct, @OpenBall, that is the discrete topology on $\mathbb N$.

Comment: @RossMillikan This is a question for my understanding of compact sets. I came up with the equivalence in question suddenly; and I think it may be interesting to know when such things hold although discrete case is trivial. So I would say coarse enough to be non-trivial?

Comment: Every finite space, whatever the topology,  has that property.

Comment: @WilliamElliot True. I should have added the space to be infinite.

Comment: In the opposite direction, Noetherian spaces (useful in algebraic geometry) have the property that *every* open set is (quasi) compact.

Comment: Of course, if all non-trivial open subsets of a space are infinite, and none of them are compact, then this statement is vacuously true. So $\mathbb R^n$ has your property, because no open sets are compact, and no open sets are finite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in my comment above, in quite a few topologies, there are no finite open sets and no compact open sets. In these cases, your statement is vacuously true.

For example, $X=\mathbb R$ with the standard topology has your property, because no open sets are finite, and no open sets are compact.

The rest of my examples will have cases with finite open sets.

Let $X=\mathbb N$ with the topology where the open sets $U$ have the property that $n\in U$ and $m\leq n$ implies $m\in U$. This has your property, since the only infinite open set is all of $X$, and it is not compact.

Given a topology $\tau$ on $X$, and an $x\in X$, define a topology $\tau_x$ which includes:
(1) Any subset of $X\setminus\{x\}$ and
(2) Any superset of a $U\in \tau$ such that $x\in U$.

Then, in certain circumstances, I think $\tau_x$ will have the property you want. (I think the property is that for any $U\in \tau$ with $x\in U$, there exists $V\in\tau$ with $x\in V$ such that $U\setminus V$ is infinite.)

This space is "close to discrete," in that it is discrete on $X\setminus\{x\}$ but more complicated around $x$. (It can be thought of as encoding the idea of "continuity at $x$.") It is Hausdorff when $\tau$ is Hausdorff (since $\tau\subseteq \tau_x$).

Comment: Good to know $X = \mathbb{N}$, which is non-trivial for me. Incidentally, is there a name for that topology?

Comment: It's called the "right order topology." https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_topology

Comment: It seems that this is left order topology, but thanks anyway.

Comment: Whoops, yes. @Orat